# Java to Python conversion of StringTokenizer class

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to convert java code to python for tokenization. You can find java implementation [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/StringTokenizer-source.html).

I'm getting some syntax error in the implementation of my code written as follows:

```
class StringTokenizer:
    def __init__(self, text, delim=" \t\n\r\f", returnDelims=False):
        self.text = text
        self.delim = delim
        self.retDelims = returnDelims
        self.length = len(text)
        self.pos = 0

    def hasMoreTokens(self):
        if not self.retDelims:
            while (self.pos < self.length)  and (self.delim.find(self.text[self.pos])>=0):
                self.pos+=1
        return self.pos < self.length

    def nextToken(self,delim=" \t\n\r\f"):
        self.delim = delim
        if (self.pos < self.length) and (self.delim.find(self.text[self.pos])>=0):
            if self.retDelims:
                return self.text[self.pos : self.pos+=1]
            while (self.pos+=1 < self.length) and (self.delim.find(self.text[self.pos])>=0):
                pass
        if (self.pos < self.length):
            start = self.pos
            while (self.pos+=1 < self.length) and (self.delim.find(self.text[self.pos])<0):
                pass
            return self.text[start:self.pos]
```

The error is a syntax error which is not allowing me to use pos+=1 in the 19th line.

Stack Trace:

```
 File "<ipython-input-4-f942f63e931b>", line 19
    return self.text[self.pos : self.pos+=1]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thnaks

Comment: show the stack trace of error. also which is the 19th line. I mean there are multiple pos+=1 and I don't know if you count space as 1 line of not. So show exactly where the error is and also the stack trace or output of error you are getting.

Comment: try changing it to `temp = self.pos`, then `self.pos += 1` and then `return self.text[temp: self.pos]`

Comment: Then its not giving me the result

Comment: I tried with this code: 

`st1 = StringTokenizer("JAVA : Code : String", " :",  True)

while st1.hasMoreTokens():
    print(st1.nextToken())`

Which should give me :

`JAVA
 
:
 
Code
 
:
 
String


`

Comment: what you mean by "not giving the result". If it's not a syntax error anymore, then probably it is your logic error. But the syntax error should not be an issue anymore.

Comment: Also, don't do this `while self.pos += 1 < self.length`. It will give you syntax error.